# How to read an XML file and validate with the data from a table

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I am in the creation of a functionality that allows loading XML files but before loading them I need to verify their content, I do not know if it is the correct way but I was thinking of something like first reading the XML to review its content and then validating it with the data that I have stored in a database table.

At the moment what I have developed so far is the loading of the XML file using AJAX and PHP as follows.

This is part of the form with which I load my XML files

```html
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> File XML:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="XmlToUpload" class="btn" accept=".xml" required>
              </div>
                    </div>
                    

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success">Upload Documents</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

The following is the JQuery function with which I load the document and validate its format

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#upload").on("click", function(){
        const ArchivoXml = $("#XmlToUpload").prop('files')[0];          

        
        if (ArchivoXml.type !== 'text/xml') {
            $('#XmlToUpload').val('');
            //$('#pdfToUpload').val('');
            alert('Please select the files with the correct format');
            return;
          }

        const datosForm = new FormData;

        datosForm.append("XmlToUpload", ArchivoXml);
       
        const filePath="server.php"
        //console.log(ArchivoXml);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: datosForm,
            url:filePath
        }).done(function(data){
            alert(data)
        }).fail(function(){
            alert('The file could not be loaded')
        });       
    });   
});
```

The following is the PHP code with which I indicate the path where it will be stored

**server.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES["XmlToUpload"])){
        $archivo = $_FILES["XmlToUpload"]["name"];
        $ruta ="XML/";

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["XmlToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$ruta.$archivo)){
            echo "Successfully uploaded";
        }else{
            echo "Error";
        }          
    }else {
        echo "A file was not selected";
    }
?>
```

As I mentioned at the beginning of the question, I need to validate the content of the XML and validate it with the information found in a database table.

The structure of the XML file will contain the following information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Voucher Version="3.3" Total="45264.13">
    <cfdi:Issuer Rfc="ABC123456AB1" Name="JOHN DOE"/>
     <cfdi:Concepts>
         <cfdi:Concept UnitValue="93.80">
        </cfdi:Concept>
    </cfdi:Concepts>
     <cfdi:Plugin>
        <tfd:Digital Version="1.1" />
    </cfdi:Plugin>
</cfdi:Voucher>
```

Here the data that I am interested in validating are `Total="45264.13"` and `Rfc="ABC123456AB1"`

In addition to this, I started the task of creating a Stored Procedure in SQLServer to obtain the information from the Database and thus compare with the XML data and the value of the fields of the table in the Database.

```
USE [dbtest]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sptest]
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sptest]
    
AS
BEGIN
    
    Select VTB.RFC as 'RFC',
           LRC.QTY as 'QTY',  
           PL.PRICE as 'Price',
           (PL.PRICE *LRC.QTY) * 1.16 as 'Total'
    from PACKING RC  
        inner join VTABLE VTB on VTB.COLUMN = RC.INVOICE
        inner join TRANS LRC on (LRC.PACKING = RC.RECID)
        inner join PURCH PL on (PL.NUMBER =LRC.NUM and PL.PURCH =RC.PURCH)      
END
```

I hope someone can guide me a bit with this functionality that I am creating.

**Update:**

With the aim of giving a much faster validation so that the data is equal to the content of the XML, now I have decided to obtain them in the front, that is, to show them in the same view where I load the XML as follows:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="lblNombreVisita" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">RFC:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRfc" disabled>
                        </div>
                     </div>
           <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="lblNombreVisita" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Total:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtTotal" disabled>
                        </div>
                     </div>

<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> Archivo XML:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="XmlToUpload" class="btn" accept=".xml" required>
                  </div>
                        </div>
                        

              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success">Subir Documentos</button>
              </div>
          </form>
```

Likewise, if someone finds how to validate them to be equal to the values ​​found in the database, it is also valid or if they can be directly validated with the values ​​that I am obtaining in the text fields that I just added, it is also valid.

Comment: The XML example is invalid. It is missing the namespace definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the XML you shared is the actual XML passed to SQL Server, you are going to run into challenges with namespaces. They need to be declared in the XML and then again when querying for data.

Here's an example that returns the values for `Total` and `Rfc` as you have shared.

```
-- String holding the supplied XML.

DECLARE @my_xml varchar(MAX) = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Voucher Version="3.3" Total="45264.13">
  <cfdi:Issuer Rfc="ABC123456AB1" Name="JOHN DOE"/>
  <cfdi:Concepts>
    <cfdi:Concept UnitValue="93.80"></cfdi:Concept>
  </cfdi:Concepts>
  <cfdi:Plugin>
    <tfd:Digital Version="1.1" />
  </cfdi:Plugin>
</cfdi:Voucher>';

-- Remove the XML declaration and add the required namespaces via a "root" wrapper.
-- Note: You could use STUFF to place root after the declaration and keep it, but this was faster.

SELECT 
    @my_xml = REPLACE ( @my_xml, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', '' ),
    @my_xml = CONCAT ( '<root xmlns:cfdi="uri" xmlns:tfd="uri">', @my_xml, '</root>' );

-- Return the values for Total and Rfc.

SELECT
    t.c.value('declare namespace cfdi="uri"; (@Total)[1]', 'decimal(18,2)') AS Total,
    t.c.value('declare namespace cfdi="uri"; (cfdi:Issuer/@Rfc)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Rfc
FROM ( SELECT CAST ( @my_xml AS xml ) AS xml_data ) AS x
CROSS APPLY x.xml_data.nodes( 'declare namespace cfdi="uri"; //root/cfdi:Voucher' ) t(c);
```

**Returns**

```
+----------+--------------+
|  Total   |     Rfc      |
+----------+--------------+
| 45264.13 | ABC123456AB1 |
+----------+--------------+
```

Assuming I understand your validation and requirements, you could adjust your stored procedure to accept your XML as a parameter and then do your validation/handling of it accordingly.

Here is an example for reference:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sptest] (
    @my_xml varchar(MAX)   
)
AS
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE
        @rfc varchar(50), @qty int, @price decimal(18,2), @total decimal(18,2);

    /*****************************************/
    /*      Fetch values for validation      */
    /*****************************************/

    SELECT
        @rfc = VTB.RFC AS 'RFC',
        @qty = LRC.QTY AS 'QTY',  
        @price = PL.PRICE AS 'Price',
        @total = (PL.PRICE * LRC.QTY) * 1.16 AS 'Total'
    FROM PACKING AS RC  
    INNER JOIN VTABLE AS VTB 
        ON VTB.COLUMN = RC.INVOICE
    INNER JOIN TRANS AS LRC 
        ON (LRC.PACKING = RC.RECID)
    INNER JOIN PURCH AS PL 
        ON (PL.NUMBER =LRC.NUM and PL.PURCH =RC.PURCH)      

    /*****************************************/
    /*     Fetch XML values to validate      */
    /*****************************************/

    DECLARE
        @x_rfc varchar(50), @x_total decimal(18,2);

    -- Remove the XML declaration and add the required namespaces via a "root" wrapper.
    -- Note: You could use STUFF to place root after the declaration and keep it, but this was faster.

    SELECT 
        @my_xml = REPLACE ( @my_xml, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', '' ),
        @my_xml = CONCAT ( '<root xmlns:cfdi="uri" xmlns:tfd="uri">', @my_xml, '</root>' );

    -- Return the values for Total and Rfc.

    SELECT
        @x_total = t.c.value('declare namespace cfdi="uri"; (@Total)[1]', 'decimal(18,2)'),
        @x_rfc = t.c.value('declare namespace cfdi="uri"; (cfdi:Issuer/@Rfc)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
    FROM ( SELECT CAST ( @my_xml AS xml ) AS xml_data ) AS x
    CROSS APPLY x.xml_data.nodes( 'declare namespace cfdi="uri"; //root/cfdi:Voucher' ) t(c);

    /*****************************************/
    /*        Validate and handle XML        */
    /*****************************************/

    IF @rfc = @x_rfc AND @total = @x_total BEGIN

        -- Validation Success --
        -- Insert your XML to database...

    END ELSE BEGIN

        -- Validation Failure --
        -- Throw and error or whatever you need...

    END

END
GO
```

I am making a lot of assumptions here (like both your XML and SELECT contain only a single record), but it should get you moving forward.

Comment: Your answer seems to be working, but how can I apply a validation in the code that I add in my question? I mean that the XML file is not allowed to be loaded until this verification is performed

Comment: Your stored procedure can be responsible for both validation and insertion. I see where you are selecting data, but not what you're validating. Show your validation and I will see if I can help further.

Comment: It is that it is the validation that I am needing, I need to do a validation where the values ​​indicated in the question are read and compared with the data of the table in the database and if they are correct allow to upload the file of the Otherwise it generates an error and does not allow it to load

Comment: Are you only comparing RDC and Total? Do they need to be equal to values extracted from your DB?

Comment: It is correct, for now I am interested in validating the RFC and Total, and they must be equal to the values ​​extracted from the database

Comment: Added a suggested update for your SP to my answer.

Comment: Here we return to the same thing, I need validation but from javascript it is as simple as going to read the XML file to verify what RFC and Total contains and if it is correct that it allows uploading the file, I remind you that the file is being loaded directly into a folder on my server

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression you wanted SQL server to handle your validation. JavaScript is a whole other scenario. Perhaps someone else will take a crack at it.

Comment: No, it was for this reason that I added all the JQuery and PHP code on how to load the file so that the validation is performed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to validate the xml data first with the data stored in database so instead of moving the xml file to a permanent location, I would suggest you to read the file and get the values of required fields which you want to validate. To get the values from xml file, You'll have to use any PHP provided XML library like `DOMDocument`, `XMLReader`, `SimpleXML` or you can use this [XML2Array](https://github.com/digitickets/lalit/blob/master/src/XML2Array.php) to convert xml to an associative array to easily get the value

```php
if (isset($_FILES["XmlToUpload"])) {
    // Create a unique filename
    $fileName = $_FILES["XmlToUpload"]["name"];
    $ext = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $archivo = uniqid($fileName, true);
    $ruta ="XML/";
    
    $xmlData = file_get_contents($_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name']);
        
    $arr = XML2Array::createArray($xmlData);
    
    //Check whether this array contains the required keys or not i.e. Total & Rfc
    if (! isset($arr['cfdi:Voucher']['@attributes']['Total'])) {
        echo "Error";
        exit();
    }
    $totalAmount = $arr['cfdi:Voucher']['@attributes']['Total'];
    
    if (! isset($arr['cfdi:Voucher']['cfdi:Issuer']['@attributes']['Rfc'])) {
        echo "Error";
        exit();
    }
    $rfc = $arr['cfdi:Voucher']['cfdi:Issuer']['@attributes']['Rfc'];
    
    // Validating $totalAmount & $rfc with the data in database
    // Connect to database (Sql Server)
    $serverName = "serverName\\sqlexpress";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    
    if ($conn === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    
    $sql = "Select VTB.RFC as 'RFC',
            LRC.QTY as 'QTY',  
            PL.PRICE as 'Price',
            (PL.PRICE *LRC.QTY) * 1.16 as 'Total'
        from PACKING RC  
            inner join VTABLE VTB on VTB.COLUMN = RC.INVOICE
            inner join TRANS LRC on (LRC.PACKING = RC.RECID)
            inner join PURCH PL on (PL.NUMBER =LRC.NUM and PL.PURCH =RC.PURCH)   
        where VTB.RFC = ? AND ((PL.PRICE * LRC.QTY) * 1.16) = ?";
    
    $params = array($rfc, $totalAmount);
    $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params, $options);
    $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );
    
    if ($row_count === false) {
        echo "Error";
    } else {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["XmlToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$ruta.$archivo)){
            echo "Successfully uploaded";
        }else{
            echo "Error";
        }
    }  
} else {
    echo "A file was not selected";
}
```

Comment: When I try to execute the changes of your answer in my development I find this error `Fatal error: Class 'XML2Array' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\GUI-PID\server.php on line 31` Is there anything else I need to add to the code?

Comment: @user11804298 you need to get `XML2Array` class from here https://github.com/digitickets/lalit/blob/master/src/XML2Array.php in order to get this working

Comment: In addition to the error that I commented previously, I do not see where the validation is performed to equal the values of the database

Comment: @user11804298 I've put comment in the code where you'll have to perform the validation.

Comment: The validation is what I am requiring, I pass the same as with the other answer, I do all a code in SQL Server but without the initial validation that I require to solve my problem, my question very clearly says _How to read an XML file and **validate with the data from a table**_, I appreciate if you can support me with this validation that is needed

Comment: @user11804298 Based on your question `read an XML file and validate with the data from a table` I've updated the answer. You'll need to make necessary changes by yourself. Instead of Stored Procedure I've used the `select` query directly to check the rfc and totalAmount from XML file

Comment: I see that in the query that you added directly you did not add the RFC and Total parameters, you can add them please to test it in my development and give it validity to your answer

Comment: @user11804298 RFC and Total is getting added to the query in `sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params, $options)` where $params contains these as binding parameters from the select query and in select query `?` will be replaced by the actual values

Comment: I keep having problems using `XML2Array` at the beginning of my server.php file I declare it as follows `use XML2Array;` and additionally create an `XML2Array.php` file with all the code found [here](https://github.com/digitickets/lalit/blob/master/src/XML2Array.php), is there something additional that I need to add?

Comment: @user11804298 change the database credentials and it should work

Comment: What has to do with the issue of changing the database credentials, are they the ones I use in my development, are credentials used elsewhere?

Comment: yes, change this `$serverName = "serverName\\sqlexpress";` and this `$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");`

Comment: The use of XML2Array is getting a bit complicated for me, to give it a faster validation, it seems to you if you validate it with the data that I am showing in the front, as well as I added it in my last update.

Comment: It is possible that I can validate with the data that I am showing in the view where I load the xml, it is making it difficult for me to do it directly to the DB